# Ionic cordova run android webpage not available

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

First post so please excuse me, im facing this problem where if i try to run my ionic app on my phone, it will give me error saying the webpage is not available. I dont have any errors showing in my console, so i have no idea what is going on.[edge dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB3cN.png) / [the error i get when app opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wfjf.jpg) / [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G37Gv.jpg)

I have tried running the app through ionic serve, and there seems to be no problem..but for some reason i cant run this on my phone.

Im stuck on this and would really appreciate the help.
Im not sure what more i should include, so please let know if you guys need anything else.

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload
[INFO] Hardware device(s) found for android. Using --device.
> ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-serve --host=localhost --port=8100 --platform=android

[ng] chunk {} 0.js, 0.js.map () 31.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] WARNING in C:\Users\bansa\Sk\project\src\test.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
[ng] Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
[ng] WARNING in C:\Users\bansa\Sk\project\src\environments\environment.prod.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
[ng] Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
[ng] chunk {m16} 16.js, 16.js.map () 32.8 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {add-inquiry-add-inquiry-module} add-inquiry-add-inquiry-module.js, add-inquiry-add-inquiry-module.js.map (add-inquiry-add-inquiry-module) 11.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {add-modal-add-modal-module} add-modal-add-modal-module.js, add-modal-add-modal-module.js.map (add-modal-add-modal-module) 4.53 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {adduser-adduser-module} adduser-adduser-module.js, adduser-adduser-module.js.map (adduser-adduser-module) 4.45 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {common} common.js, common.js.map (common) 21.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {cordova} cordova.js, cordova.js.map (cordova) 63.5 kB [entry] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {default~adduser-adduser-module~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module} default~adduser-adduser-module~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module.js, default~adduser-adduser-module~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module.js.map (default~adduser-adduser-module~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module) 14.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~updatebranch-updatebranch-module~use~b4dc958b} default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~updatebranch-updatebranch-module~use~b4dc958b.js, default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~updatebranch-updatebranch-module~use~b4dc958b.js.map (default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~updatebranch-updatebranch-module~use~b4dc958b) 17.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~updateuser-updateuser-module~user-in~5dd05b32} default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~updateuser-updateuser-module~user-in~5dd05b32.js, default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~updateuser-updateuser-module~user-in~5dd05b32.js.map (default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~updateuser-updateuser-module~user-in~5dd05b32) 18.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~user-detail-user-detail-module} default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~user-detail-user-detail-module.js, default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~user-detail-user-detail-module.js.map (default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~user-detail-user-detail-module) 22.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~user-inquiry-user-inquiry-module} default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~user-inquiry-user-inquiry-module.js, default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~user-inquiry-user-inquiry-module.js.map (default~disp-user-disp-user-module~disp-user2-disp-user2-module~user-inquiry-user-inquiry-module) 21.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {disp-user-disp-user-module} disp-user-disp-user-module.js, disp-user-disp-user-module.js.map (disp-user-disp-user-module) 21.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {disp-user2-disp-user2-module} disp-user2-disp-user2-module.js, disp-user2-disp-user2-module.js.map (disp-user2-disp-user2-module) 22 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {focus-visible-15ada7f7-js} focus-visible-15ada7f7-js.js, focus-visible-15ada7f7-js.js.map (focus-visible-15ada7f7-js) 2.11 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {home-home-module} home-home-module.js, home-home-module.js.map (home-home-module) 8.68 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {input-shims-b956f530-js} input-shims-b956f530-js.js, input-shims-b956f530-js.js.map (input-shims-b956f530-js) 16.3 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {keyboard-dd970efc-js} keyboard-dd970efc-js.js, keyboard-dd970efc-js.js.map (keyboard-dd970efc-js) 6.16 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {login-login-module} login-login-module.js, login-login-module.js.map (login-login-module) 13 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 54.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {main-admin-main-admin-module} main-admin-main-admin-module.js, main-admin-main-admin-module.js.map (main-admin-main-admin-module) 22 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 268 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {polyfills-core-js} polyfills-core-js.js, polyfills-core-js.js.map (polyfills-core-js) 92.4 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {polyfills-css-shim} polyfills-css-shim.js, polyfills-css-shim.js.map (polyfills-css-shim) 10.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {polyfills-dom} polyfills-dom.js, polyfills-dom.js.map (polyfills-dom) 38.5 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 11.2 kB [entry] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {shadow-css-fc98efba-js} shadow-css-fc98efba-js.js, shadow-css-fc98efba-js.js.map (shadow-css-fc98efba-js) 15.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {status-tap-a9bf301d-js} status-tap-a9bf301d-js.js, status-tap-a9bf301d-js.js.map (status-tap-a9bf301d-js) 1.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 102 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {swipe-back-0a6a44c8-js} swipe-back-0a6a44c8-js.js, swipe-back-0a6a44c8-js.js.map (swipe-back-0a6a44c8-js) 3.05 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {swiper-bundle-95afeea2-js} swiper-bundle-95afeea2-js.js, swiper-bundle-95afeea2-js.js.map (swiper-bundle-95afeea2-js) 200 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {tap-click-252af35a-js} tap-click-252af35a-js.js, tap-click-252af35a-js.js.map (tap-click-252af35a-js) 6.22 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {updatebranch-updatebranch-module} updatebranch-updatebranch-module.js, updatebranch-updatebranch-module.js.map (updatebranch-updatebranch-module) 4.7 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {updateuser-updateuser-module} updateuser-updateuser-module.js, updateuser-updateuser-module.js.map (updateuser-updateuser-module) 4.6 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {user-detail-user-detail-module} user-detail-user-detail-module.js, user-detail-user-detail-module.js.map (user-detail-user-detail-module) 4.63 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {user-inquiry-user-inquiry-module} user-inquiry-user-inquiry-module.js, user-inquiry-user-inquiry-module.js.map (user-inquiry-user-inquiry-module) 4.68 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5.36 MB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] Date: 2020-08-17T04:50:03.895Z - Hash: 6076b7f4a0a4f6e0985d - Time: 13946ms
[INFO] ... and 41 additional chunks
[ng] : Compiled successfully.

[INFO] Development server running!

   Local: http://localhost:8100

   Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

> cordova.cmd build android --device
> native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk --device --forward 8100:8100
[native-run] Selected hardware device 8d0ad9fd
[native-run] Forwarded device port 8100 to host port 8100
[native-run] Installing platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk...
[native-run] Starting application activity io.ionic.starter/io.ionic.starter.MainActivity...
[native-run] Run Successful
```

UPDATE:

I tried to run it without live reload and got this error. [without livereload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUHNT.png) I will paste my config.xml below.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Are you getting 404 Error. Its looks like you need to look into HashLocationStrategy.

Comment: try to run app without livereload and if you have still proble than run ionic info and paste your configuation here.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot Yes, through the edge tools it shows the 404 error.

Comment: @abhayjani still got error without livereload, i have updated post with config